# How can I describe mathematical equation of GLMM, rather than R language

Tags: r, glmm

How should I describe the below equation for someone who does not know R languages:

glmer(A ~ as.factor(B) + (1|C)),

where A is a response variable, B is a explanatory variable, and C is the random effect, modeled by using *glmer* function in the *lme4* package.

What is the general mathematical equation for this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'random(C)': this has no standard meaning in `R`, mathematics, or English.

Comment: I am sorry for the uncertain description. In R language, the equation is glmer(A ~ as.factor(B) + (1|C)), using the glmer function in the lme4 package. (1|C) represents a random effect in GLMM.